# What is the way to determine traits in dialogue?

Tags: divinity-original-sin

I am having a hard time determining the outcomes of the dialogue between party members, for example what will be Romantic or Pragmatic? is there a way to discern this whether in game or from some other source outside the game?

Ideally I would like to be able to determine how the answers are before I commit to them, thus gaining a bonus to a skill I dont ever use nor care about.

Answer (score 1):

I think it's intentional that you only find out afterwards. As it's not very obvious from the dialogue which trait pair is going to be affected (especially when it's one you haven't discovered yet), the only way I found to do this was to save before initiating conversations, see what happens and then repeat with the desirable outcome (since once you know the traits, it's usually easy to tell which answer goes in which direction).

There is a [list of the existing traits](http://www.larian.com/forums/ubbthreads.php?ubb=showflat&Number=506572), but I have yet to find a list of the conversations that affect them (and I'm not sure I'd want to, as that'd be very spoilerific).